# how to sort and arrange a text file in java to group lines

Tags: java, sorting, text-files

Really struggling to work this out...

I have a text file with data like this (17000 lines of it)

```
45226   1
45226   1
45226   1
45226   3
45226   5
23470   1
45226   5
45226   5
29610   4
37417   2
37417   3
37948   1
```

What I want to do is sort the text file (using java) so all the left numbers are grouped if the right value is 1.
or the left value is group if the right is not equal to 1 (so any other number). 
for example (but doesn't have to be like this)

```
3 x 45226   1
4 x 45226   MIXED
1 x 23470   1
1 x 29610   MIXED
2 x 37417   MIXED
1 x 37948   1
```

I know I may need to use array? or some sort of sort? but I just can't work it out :'(

Any help, code or suggestions - greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to group from all file or from sequence? That is: 45226 1; 45227 1; 45226 1; have to be 2x45226 1; 1x45227 1 or 1x45226 1; 1x45227 1; 1x45226 1? Oops, sorry. I saw it :)

Comment: from the whole file - so 2x45226 1; 1x45227 1 would be the correct method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code:

```
public class Sort {


private static class Counter {

    private int one;
    private int mixed;

    public void incrementOne() {
        one++;
    }

    public void incrementMixed() {
        mixed++;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Counter> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Counter>();
    String fileName = "input.txt";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        String key = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String value = tokenizer.nextToken();
        Counter counter = map.get(key);
        if (counter == null) {
            counter = new Counter();
            map.put(key, counter);
        }
        if (value.equals("1")) {
            counter.incrementOne();
        } else {
            counter.incrementMixed();
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
    for(Map.Entry<String, Counter>entry:map.entrySet()){
        Counter counter = entry.getValue();
        if(counter.one>0){
            writer.write(String.valueOf(counter.one));
            writer.write(" x ");
            writer.write(entry.getKey());
            writer.write("   1");
            writer.newLine();
        }
        if(counter.mixed>0){
            writer.write(String.valueOf(counter.mixed));
            writer.write(" x ");
            writer.write(entry.getKey());
            writer.write("   MIXED");
            writer.newLine();
        }
    }
    writer.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'd generate two maps, one for when the right is 1 and one for all other right-hand values. Each map maps left-hand values to count of occurrences. You can then populate the maps by looping through the data. In pseudo-Java:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> onesMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Map(Integer, Integer> otherMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (each left/right pair) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = right == 1 ? onesMap : otherMap;
    Integer count = map.get(left);
    map.put(left, count == null ? 1 : (1 + count));
}
```

At the end, the key/value pairs give you the counts you need for each left value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a map to store the data:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new TreeSet<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
```

The *key* is the value of the first line and, as it is not unique, the maps value is a set which holds the various values from the second column.

```
private void addLine(String line) {
  String[] fields = line.split("\\s*");
  Integer key = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
  Integer value = Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
  Set<Integer> set = map.get(value);
  if (set == null) {
     set = new HashSet<Integer>();
     map.put(key, set);
  }
  set.add(value);
}
```

Once the file is read, you can get the result for each number like this:

```
private String getResult(Integer key) {
  Set<Integer> values = map.get(key);
  if (values == null) {
     return null;  // key not in map (unknown number)
  } else if (values.size() == 1) {
     return values.iterator().next().toString();
  } else {
    return "MIXED";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map1=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Map<Integer, Integer> mapMixed=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

void addValues(int value, int num){
   if (num==1){
     if (map1.get(value)==null) map1.put(value,0);
     map1.put(value,map1.get(value)+1);
   } else {
     if (mapMixed.get(value)==null) mapMixed.put(value,0);
     mapMixed.put(value,mapMixed.get(value)+1);
   }
}
```

and after it you have to print maps:

```
void printIt(){
   Set<Integer> keys=map1.keySet();
   keys.AddAll(mapMixed.keySet());
   for (int key:keys){
       if (map1.get(key)!=null) println(map1.get(key)+"x"+key+" 1");
       if (mapMixed.get(key)!=null) println(mapMixed.get(key)+"x"+key+" MIXED"); 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use two [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) instances from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) - one for "mixed" values and one for "1" values. All you need is a count of the number of values, after all - and that's exactly what `Multiset` gives you.

So you'd use something like:

```
final Multiset<Integer> mixed = new HashMultiset<Integer>();
final Multiset<Integer> one = new HashMultiset<Integer>();

Files.readLines(new File(...), Charsets.UTF8,

    new LineProcessor<Void>() {
      @Override Void getResult() { return null; }

      @Override void processLine(String line) {
          // TODO: Split line into two integers
          int value = ...;
          int type = ...;

          Multiset<Integer> set = type == 1 ? one : mixed;
          set.add(value);
      }
    });
```

You can then iterate over those two sets, and find the value and the count of each entry.